# How to check for the position of a child element with XPath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath

I have the following problem. Given the following architecture:

```
<div id="div">
  <span>Some content</span>
  <span class="active">Some more content</span>
  <span>Even more content</span>
<div>
```

Now, what I want to find out is if the `span` having the class `active` is the last of the `div`s children. My try below matches he last child that matches the conditions, but does not evaluate if its the last child in the tree:

```
//div[@id="div"]/span[@class="active" and last()]
```

Comment: You have an extra `)` in your XPath, is that just a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s an expression that does what you want and may help explain what’s happening and why your attempt doesn’t work:

```
//div[@id="div"]/span[last()][@class="active"]
```

The [`last()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-last) function returns the position of the last element in the current evaluation context (in this case the number of `spans` in the div) so it evaluates to a number. When a number is combined with `and` in a predicate it is converted to a boolean using the [`boolean()` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean), and so as long as the value isn’t zero it will evaluate to `true`. So your expression effectively becomes:

```
//div[@id="div"]/span[@class="active" and true()]
```

which is the same as

```
//div[@id="div"]/span[@class="active"]
```

and doesn’t check that the node is in the last position.

When a predicate evaluates to a number, as in `[3]` or `[last()]`, it is treated as if it was the same as e.g. `[position()=3]` or `[position()=last()]`. I suspect you were expecting this in your expression, but this only happens when the number is the sole thing in the predicate. You need to either make sure that the number is in its own predicate as in my expression above, or explicitly use `position()=` as in [Joel M. Lamsen’s anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26360136/214790).

Answer (score 1):

use `position()` function. Try something like:

```
//div[@id="div")]/span[@class="active" and position()=last()]
```